# Yii2 label for не работает

Tags: yii2, form

Как добавить атрибут for для label ? Пробую так, не работает

```
$form->field($user, 'approve')->checkbox(
    ['id'=>'user-approve','labelOptions'=>['for'=>'user-approve']]
)
```

А к примеру так работает

```
$form->field($user, 'approve')->checkbox(
    ['id'=>'user-approve','labelOptions'=>['for111'=>'user-approve']]
)
```

Comment: А разве у `label`автоматом не ставится атрибут при добавлении `id` основному элементу?

Comment: Нет, во всяком случае у меня нет.

Comment: Вообще, если честно, работа с формами в Yii начинает меня немного раздражать :(

Answer (score -1):

А почему вы не хотите использовать что то подобное?

```
$form->field($user, 'approve')->checkbox(
['id'=>'user-approve']-label('sometext', ['for'=> ''user-approve''])
```